# Get all parameters passed to a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, windows-scripting

I have a function as following. It generates a string as per the parameters passed.

```powershell
function createSentenceAccordingly {
Param([Parameter(mandatory = $false)] [String] $name,
      [Parameter(mandatory = $false)] [String] $address,
      [Parameter(mandatory = $false)] [String] $zipcode,
      [Parameter(mandatory = $false)] [String] $city,
      [Parameter(mandatory = $false)] [String] $state)

    $stringRequired = "Hi,"

    if($name){
        $stringRequired += "$name, "
    }
    if($address){
        $stringRequired += "You live at $address, "
    }
    if($zipcode){
        $stringRequired += "in the zipcode:$zipcode, "
    }
    if($name){
        $stringRequired += "in the city:$city, "
    }
    if($name){
        $stringRequired += "in the state: $state."
    }

    return $stringRequired
}
```

So, basically the function returns something depending upon the parameters passed. I wanted to avoid the if loops as much as possible and access all the parameters at once.

Can I access all the parameters in an array or a hashmap ? As I should be using named parameters, $args cannot be used here. If I could access all the parameters at once (may be in an array like $args or a hashamp), my plan is to use that to create the returnstring dynamically.

In the future, the parameters for the function will increase a lot and I donot want to keep on writing if loops for each additional parameter.

Thanks in advance, :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`$PSBoundParameters` variable](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/01/14/powershell-boundparameters-variable.aspx) is a hashtable that contains only the parameters explicitly passed to the function.

A better way for what you want might be to use [parameter sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx) so that you can name specific combinations of parameters (don't forget to make the appropriate parameters mandatory within those sets).

Then you can do something like:

```powershell
switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'NameOnly' {
        # Do Stuff
    }
    'NameAndZip' {
        # Do Stuff
    }
    # etc.
}
```

Comment: I would also add that if you are planning to pass an inordinately large number of parameters to a function, I feel that putting all those parameters into an object or data structure and passing that is usually a better idea.

Comment: @EBGreen I'm on the fence about that when it comes to powershell. I think it depends highly on the situation. With individual parameters you can let powershell do type checking, validation, use parameter sets, etc. Since we can't create classes (until v5), I think separate is often better, but not always. At least we have splatting to more easily call functions with lots of parameters.

Comment: It is true that you can't write real classes, but you can create objects with methods and properties that let you do pretty much anything that you would do with an instance of a class.

Comment: That is a good point, I use those features all the time, but you can only create instances in that way, so you can't write your function in such a way that it expects any of those properties or methods (not without writing a ton of validation code). But again while I think that individual params have some distinct advantages, I also think it's very situational and there is a place for sending in a lot of data as an object or hashtable or something.